# how to move by a word in command line in tcsh?

Tags: command-line, tcsh

let's say the command is 
"ls word1 word2 word3"

I want to move the cursor from end of line to "word2" but do not want to clear "word3" in process. Just jump back by two words and reach beginning of "word2"

is there any keyboard shortcut to jump word backward and forward without deleting the word on command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When tcsh's line editor is configured in `emacs` mode (which is the default, use `bindkey -e` to go back to it if you had enabled `vi` mode earlier):

```
% bindkey | grep word | egrep 'for|back'
"^[^H"         -> backward-delete-word
"^[B"          -> backward-word
"^[F"          -> forward-word
"^[b"          -> backward-word
"^[f"          -> forward-word
"^[^?"         -> backward-delete-word
```

So <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then <kbd>b</kbd> / <kbd>f</kbd> (or <kbd>B</kbd> / <kbd>F</kbd>), which are the sequences that terminals usually send upon pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>/<kbd>f</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>b</kbd>/<kbd>f</kbd> for the uppercase ones).

That's the same as you would do in the `emacs` editor.

In `vi` mode (after `bindkey -v`), you'd use the usual `vi` motion commands in vi command mode (`b`ack, `w`ord, `e`nd, and their uppercase equivalents for WORD motions (whitespace separated words)).

Answer (score 1):

"Alt+b" for backwards and "Alt+f" for forwards. Also "Alt+backspace" should delete a word backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the shortcuts as expected by a Windows user (just put these in your `~/.cshrc` or paste in your shell):

```
# Use CTRL + left/right to move a word at a time:
bindkey '^[[1;5D' backward-word
bindkey '^[[1;5C' forward-word
```

There is also an option to use other keyboard shortcuts for these, for example:

```
# Use ALT + left/right to move a word at a time:
bindkey '^[[1;3D' backward-word
bindkey '^[[1;3C' forward-word
```